ORA-06512 numeric or value error when converting from clob to xmltype using APEX process
I have PLSQL function "ws_get_test" that returns SOAP response in CLOB format.
I try to get response with PLSQL code in APEX page:
DECLARE
l_xml_response  CLOB;
l_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
select ws_get_test(p_no => '12345' ) into l_xml_response from dual;   
l_xml XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(l_xml_response);

I get error numeric or value error ORA-06512 on line of code:
l_xml XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(l_xml_response);
I dont get this error executing this process using sql developer.
This is code of ws_get_test function:
create or replace function ws_get_test(p_no varchar2)
return  clob
as
l_envelope CLOB;
l_xml XMLTYPE;
l_result clob;
begin
l_envelope := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http:schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsei="http://wsei.test.com">

   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>

      <wsei:CatchData>

         <wsei:lk_no>' || p_no ||  '</wsei:lk_no>

      </wsei:CatchData>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>';

l_xml :=APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request(

p_url   => 'http://example.com/services/DS_CatchData',

p_action => 'urn:CatchData',

p_envelope => l_envelope

);
l_result := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.parse_xml_clob(
p_xml =>remove_namespace(l_xml),
p_xpath =>'/Envelope/Body/Data',
p_ns=> ''

);
return l_result;
END;


Pls provide a minimal reproducible example. The function ws_get_text returns "something" and that  is causing the error. So... without knowing a value that is causing the error this cannot be investigated.

I have posted the function code

The variable l_result is of type CLOB. Are you sure it always returns valid XML ? For a case where it fails - have you checked the value of l_result ? Was that valid XML ?That is where I would start, not much more I can do to help.

I checked and the value is ok, it's interesting that everything works correctly when I start the process using sql developer, but that doesn't suits me because I need to fill the APEX item with parsed xml

Version of APEX ? In the more recent versions, Hidden Items have a "Session State" attribute that can be set to CLOB. That could be the reason. If not, then maybe you could store the value in a collection (there is a CLOB column available) - so you can process it
